# Why is my while loop not adding the values for the total

Tags: python, while-loop

Had some code that I used for my for loop but it didn’t allow me to add the values I.e total+=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If thats the correct indentation then you only ever add values that you enter after an invalid input first

unindent the line appending to total weight

```
while foodweight<0 or foodweight>200:
    print("Invalid, weight cant be less than 0 or more than 200")
    foodweight=int(input("Please enter the actual weight of the food:'"))
totalweight+=foodweight
```